# Powershell replace using regex to match a row starting with a string of brackets

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace, special-characters

I'm trying to create a powershell script to modify a file and replace rows starting with "][" by a comma.

I have a file text.json with some broken JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "5413146",
    "Datasets": [
      {
        "DatasetId": "354843154864",
        "DatasetName": "testset"
      }
    ],
    "SharingAction": "Direct"
  }
][][][][][
  {
    "Id": "656156462",
    "LastRefreshTime": "may"
  }
][][
  {
    "Id": "32448542",
    "LastRefreshTime": "jan"
  }
]
```

To fix it I would need to replace the rows with multiple brackets with a comma and I need to do it with a power shell script.

I found out that I can read the contents of the file to a variable like this:

```
$text = Get-Content text.json -Raw
```

Then I can replace normal text and output the modified contents to a new file like this:

```
$text -replace 'may','june' | Out-File -FilePath text_modified.json
```

However, I'm having issues using regex to match the row with the brackets.

I found out that a regex to match a row starting with "][" would be like this:

```
^]\[.*
```

I tested with two different online regex validators and it seems to work fine. So then I believe the command I'm looking for should be:

```
$text -replace '^]\[.*',',' | Out-File -FilePath text_modified.json
```

It doesn't replace anything. Seems like it doesn't match the brackets properly.

`$text -match ']'` returns True but when I try `$text -match '^]'` it returns False. I also tried `'^\]'` which also returns False.

Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is most probably you need `'(?m)^]\[.*'`

Comment: Either change `-replace '^]\[.*',','` to ``-replace '(?m)^]\[.*',','``, or remove the `-Raw` switch from the `Get-Content` call :)

Comment: Thanks! That was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Raw` parameter of `Get-Content` returns a single string, not an array of strings representing each line in the file. Your current expression is effectively looking for the pattern at the start of input, or in this case, *the start of the file*.

If you remove `-Raw`, `-replace` will instead operate on each line of the file, and each line will be processed *as its own input*. This means that now your pattern looking for `^]\[.*` at the beginning of the input will match on the correct lines now.

And then of course, `Out-File` will write your changed file contents to disk.

---

If you really want to use `-Raw`, as mentioned in the comments you can prefix your pattern with
`(?m)`. This is the .NET regex modifier for *Multiline Mode*. Basically, this modifier makes `^` and `$` match the beginning and ending of a *line*, not just the beginning and ending of *input*.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for the explanation! Apparently the issue was in a place I didn't realize. :)